Removing ancilla qubits in Qiskit circuit
I want to remove the ancilla qubits from my quantum circuit in Qiskit.  My MWE below contains four qubits: psi0, psi1, anc0, anc1.  I want to keep psi0 and psi1 qubits and remove ancillas anc0, anc1.  Is there a way to do this?
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit, AncillaRegister, transpile
from qiskit_aer import StatevectorSimulator
import numpy as np

reg1 = QuantumRegister(2, 'psi')
reg2 = AncillaRegister(2, 'anc')
circ = QuantumCircuit(reg1, reg2)
circ.h(reg1[0])
circ.h(reg1[1])
circ.prepare_state(1/np.sqrt(2)*np.array([1,0,0,1]),reg2)
circ.cry(np.pi/2.2, control_qubit=reg2[1], target_qubit=reg1[1])
circ.cry(np.pi/1.5, control_qubit=reg2[0], target_qubit=reg1[0])
circ.prepare_state(1/np.sqrt(2)*np.array([1,0,0,1]),reg2).inverse()

simulator = StatevectorSimulator()
job = transpile(circ, simulator)  # execute circuit on qasm simulator
result = simulator.run(job,shots=128).result()  # results from the job
out_state = result.get_statevector()
print(out_state)

circ.draw('mpl')


I'm aware of a function that removes idle wires, but it loses the register's info.  Is there a different function that specifically removes ancilla qubits (and keeps the register's info)?
Edit: Provided clearer circuit example.  To clarify: Yes it will be ok to keep the ancilla qubits until the end of the circuit.  I just need psi qubits in the next part of the calculation.  I want to do a statevector simulation of psi, not anc, at the end.  Ideally I don't want to initialize a separate circuit using the output density matrix -- I prefer to use one self-contained circuit.
Edit 2: The comments below suggested simulating the full statevector of all qubits, then taking the trace to remove ancillas.  But the partial_trace function can only be applied to density matrices (see this post).

What is an equivalent method to trace over statevectors?

Is it possible to automatically determine all the ancillas and trace them out?

If there are many ancillas, will it be computationally expensive to simulate the full statevector rather than removing the ancillas before simulation?



Sorry, your question is a bit confusing. You say that solution provided in the post you linked doesn't work because "it loses the register's info". What exactly do you mean by that?

Initially the registers are labeled q0, q1, a0, a1.  After applying the remove_idle_qwires() function, the registers are labeled 0, 1, rather than q0, a0.

Sorry, I am still confused. You just changed the circuit, which now includes entangling operations on anc0 and anc1, which means the output state is not separable. This will result in having a mixed state on register psi. Do you really need to get rid of the ancillary register at this point? Is it OK to carry it all the way until the computation on psi0 psi1 finishes, and then discard it? Is this to be used only for a statevector simulation? Are you OK taking the output density matrix and initializing a separate circuit with that matrix to carry the computation?

thanks for your comments - I have added more details in my post

If you're OK keeping the anc qubits until the end of the circuit, why not run the full Statevector sim with all qubits and then trace them out?

@diemilio I tried to do this, and added some questions in the post

As I mentioned in the comments, if your psi qubits are getting entangled with the anc qubits, there is no way to recover a Statevector just for psi because the state will not be pure.
Instead, what you can extract is the density matrix of psi by tracing out the anc register. That being said, if the anc qubits are properly untentangled from psi you can always convert that DensityMatrix object back into a Statevector object.
Here are two examples, one where you have an unentangled state between psi and anc (So you can recover the Statevector for psi), and one where they are entangled.
Example 1
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit, AncillaRegister
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

reg1 = QuantumRegister(1, 'psi')
reg2 = AncillaRegister(1, 'anc')
circ = QuantumCircuit(reg1, reg2)
circ.h(reg1)
circ.x(reg2)
circ.cz(reg1,reg2)
circ.h(reg1)
circ.x(reg2)
circ.save_density_matrix(reg1)

ρ = AerSimulator().run(circ).result().data()['density_matrix']
ψ = ρ.to_statevector()
print(ψ)

This will print state Statevector([0, 1],dims=(2,)) because the state is separable.
Example 2
Change the cz gate above for a cx gate, then this line of code ψ = ρ.to_statevector() will give an error because the density matrix extracted from the simulation does not correspond to one of a pure state.
By the way, the circuit you provided as an example is of the second kind: psi and anc are entangled, so psi is not a pure state.
